# How to disable auto password filling (Keychain) while in private browsing mode in Safari?

Tags: safari, password, keychain, web-browsing, auto-complete

Keychain offers to auto complete forms including passwords even in private browsing mode. How can I disable this?

I'm using Safari 8.0.5 on Yosemite 10.10.3.

Edit: The use case here is when other people need to borrow my computer. I'll open a private browsing window for them. I don't want *my* credentials auto-filling when they visit site.

Comment: You could install a separate browser for people to use, firefox or chrome. (doesn't answer question, but might be a workaround)

Comment: Thanks, great workaround. I can use a Chrome Incognito window.

Comment: Chrome autofills from Keychain in Incognito too, if you allow Chrome access to Keychain (even if they were saved in Safari). Don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way currently offered by Apple to disable auto-fill based on the browsing mode. However, you could try to switch auto-fill on/off based browsing mode by making a trigger-effect script or macro with AppleScript or an application like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why do you need it, but my guess is to allow others to use safari without leaving traces of their activity. Private mode is not what you need. Private mode is useful when you need to access a website without tracking cookies and history and only then.

What you probably need is enabling the Guest account in user accounts. Let others login as a Guest and everything they did, including internet, will be removed upon the logout.

Comment: Think you mis-understood. I added the use-case to my question to clarify.

Comment: @guptron no, I did not misunderstand. Guest login is made specifically for the cases when you give others your computer. They can use it full-scale, save files, do whatever they want and nothing will be saved after their logout.

Comment: @Rilakkuma makes a really good point. Even if you could disable access to Keychain from Safari Private mode, all they have to do is close the Private window and they have access to your logins again. Unless you're planning to babysit them while they use it, your use case is deeply flawed.

Comment: @tubedogg Agreed, this is the best solution for my use-case. I would say my question is flawed, my use-case is completely valid.